# Get the date of the Nth day of week after the Xth day of week in a given year and month

Tags: code-golf, date

**Introduction**

In the United States, national elections are normally held on the first Tuesday after the first Monday in November.

**Challenge**

Write a program that takes a Year as integer, and a pair of (day of week as character and ordinal as integer)  and output the date as "yyyy-mm-dd"
Remember, the second pair is after the first pair.
use this for inspiration: [https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178227/get-the-date-of-the-nth-day-of-week-in-a-given-year-and-month[][1]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178227/get-the-date-of-the-nth-day-of-week-in-a-given-year-and-month%5B%5D%5B1%5D)

**Example Input and Output**

Example input:

- 2021 November Tuesday 1 Monday 1
- 2020 November Tuesday 1 Monday 1
- 2020 December Friday 2 Wednesday 1
- 2019 April Wednesday 1 Friday 1
- 2023 February Tuesday 4 Wednesday 1
- 2023 February Wednesday 5 Thursday 1
- 2022 December Sunday 5 Sunday 55

Expected output:

- "2021-11-02"
- "2020-11-03"
- "2020-12-11"
- "2019-04-10"
- "2023-02-28"
- "NA"
- "NA"

Note: the output indicated as "NA" could be any negative finding such as null, but not an error.
[1]: [Get the date of the nth day of week in a given year and month](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178227/get-the-date-of-the-nth-day-of-week-in-a-given-year-and-month)

Comment: Hi and welcome! This is an interesting challenge, but please [avoid cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/43319), and for next time, I highly recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc).

Comment: Suggested test case: 2023 February Tuesday 4 Wednesday 1

Comment: Suggested test case: 2023 February Wednesday 5 Thursday 1

Comment: Suggested test case: 2022 December Sunday 5 Sunday 55

Comment: Welcome CG.SE Lawrence. I'm curious: what's the meaning of the pairs? Is "2021 November Monday 1 Tuesday 1" valid? Also, what's the meaning of the output, regarding the input?

Comment: @gildux - The example that you ask about, `2021 November Monday 1 Tuesday 1` is asking for "**the first Tuesday that is after the first Monday in November, 2021**". You should mentally parse it as (2021 November) (Monday 1) (Tuesday 1)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin This ordering is different than the one you used in your examples. Please clarify?

Comment: Are the test cases correct? The last two seems to be fine: Dec. 1st, 2020 was a Tuesday, so the second Friday after the first Wednesday after Dec. 1st, 2020 is `2020-12-11`; and April 1st, 2019 was a Monday, so the first Wednesday after the first Friday after April 1st, 2019 is `2019-04-10`. But the first two test outputs seems to be wrong: Nov. 1st, 2021 was a Monday, so the first Tuesday after this first Monday is supposed to be `2021-11-02`; and Nov. 1st, 2020 was a Sunday, so the first Tuesday after the first Monday after Nov. 1st, 2020 is supposed to be `2020-11-03`. Or not? :S

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen, I corrected the output.

Comment: The parsing example by @JeffZeitlin is spot on.

Comment: "2023 February Tuesday 4 Wednesday 1" sorry, but why is this 'NA'? There are 4 Tuesdays in Feb 2023 - is it invalid just because the first wednesday after the 4th tuesday is in the next month?

Comment: @TKoL thanks for catching that. I have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks @JeffZeitlin The parsing was OK for me but not the meaning (i.e. "Y M A B C D" means "the C D that is after the A B in M, Y") certainly because we're not used of that saying here. Thanks for the clarification, which I think should be added to the question imho.

Comment: Is outputting `NA` if it exceeds the input month+year mandatory, or could we just calculate beyond that month? E.g. are `2023-03-08` and `2024-01-14` valid outputs for the last two test cases?

Comment: See the last 2 test cases in [my solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257338/58974) for an example of what @KevinCruijssen means. In those cases, I would suggest you allow for "undefined behaviour", rather than requiring any sort of error handling.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen   If the result is outside of the requested month and year it should not return a date and should not result in an error.

Comment: @Shaggy  any type of undefined result  is acceptable except an error

Comment: Your answers to @KevinCruijssen & myself contradict each other!

Comment: @shaggy, they are not contradictory. "should" indicates a preference not a requirement

Comment: So `2023 February Tuesday 4 Wednesday 1` is the 1st Wednesday after the 4th Tuesday of February 2023?

Comment: @bigyihsuan 2023 February Tuesday 4 Wednesday 1 is the 4th Tuesday after the 1st Wednesday of February 2023

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>102</s> <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>88</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

Oof, this made my brain itch. Possibly still some room for improvement.

```javascript
(m,t,x=0)=>g=w=>(d=new Date(...m,++x)).getDay()-w[0]||--w[1]?g(w):w!=t?g(t):d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BisIwEEDv@xXuLYPTkKT2oBBl11bsxRXFvdSCxcayi7aiwSj47zWhxyWwpzcwjzfzW9yK6/7yc9ZB3ZSqPciWnFDjXTKQ40oaOSalrJXpxYVWhFJ6wn7/DkArpePiQSAwGcufz8CS55OKGBiZd6ntpGFUtvumvjZHRY9NRQ4kE0xw5CzHTCDPgWTcAd7@auzfGrdahMJpoUfjQwytFXaxyBdze3dy4GnttvVmsV4m03SWJnHvM5l/fKdfm9XOHwsxcrGB76To/medZmEJ7Qs)

Call with `f([y,m],[W,O])([w,o])`, where:

- `y` is the year,
- `m` is the 0-indexed month,
- `W` is the 0-indexed target weekday (`0`=Sunday),
- `O` is the ordinal of `W`,
- `w` is the 0-indexed starting weekday, and,
- `o` is the ordinal of `w`

**EDIT:** Looking at the rest of the solutions coming in, they seem to be interpreting the I/O requirements of the spec a *lot* more strictly than I am. After a few read-throughs, I'm not seeing that strictness, nor would it be reasonable to assume it's that strict. Still, though, seeing as I appear to be the only one taking the requirements *this* loosely, I'll take a stab at an alternative solution on Tuesday. (It's a bank holiday weekend in Ireland)

Comment: Based on the last two test cases, if the calculated date exceeds the input year+month, it should output `NA`. But maybe it's good to verify with OP whether this is optional or mandatory, since just calculating beyond the current year+month works perfectly fine for larger input. 

Comment: Hopefully, "undefined behaviour" is sufficient in those cases, @KevinCruijssen.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>439</s> 428 bytes

- -11 thanks to ceilingcat

Most of the code is parsing the input.

```c
#define z(d)(*d-83?*d-84?*d-77?*d-87?5:3:1:d[1]-117?4:2:d[1]-117?6:0)
#define Z(d,e)(d-e+(d<e?7:0))
t[20],a,b,n,x,y;char*m,*d,*e;f(s){sscanf(s,"%d %ms %ms %d %ms %d",&y,&m,&d,&a,&e,&b);t[5]=y-=1900;x=*m-78;t[4]=n=x+4?~x?x+13?x+8?x-5?x-1?x?11:10:9:8:1:m[1]-112?7:3:m[2]-114?2:4:m[1]-97?m[2]-110?6:5:0;t[3]=1;mktime(&t);t[3]+=Z(z(e),t[6])+(a+b-2)*7+Z(z(d),z(e));mktime(&t);t[4]-n|t[5]-y||printf("%04d-%02d-%02d",y+1900,n+1,t[3]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBdb5swFH3nV1xRBdlgJsxHSaAMTZr61PVlnSY14gGws6AVpwJTQZvsr2cmJE2m7WEPvjr3nHOvfVzaP8pyv79ifFUJDq@IYWQye@6lY/XHGoYHHKZB5EU0Ykua2ZSGqR@55@Y6crB22vKIGOEYMZtbiN3wNFQi1uTSdTKSk4II0pMhLtd5Y9bEZMTk8Qq1@K1ty1woRPQZg1ndTucImU6MgRg1MRgxcmJwYhQ4lssgSwY7oQvHifvErO1wrkg/S0TSW376q097i3qqzNPeDtShaZ9SGlEnWkRzlaeeIrjqlZ5q3LHxUzfyJ2URpkfSUSGDyFHbvSyhcf1TVjVHhsQHxkoe0SvimMjldYYtlFuF7WIztEaaYTJq@M8hP7PFdgxgD9vtc1MJuUL6zPGZPXPcqehksMZoRFiUjNfgeLe/qkT51DEON61kT1XxYf1R09Q01Hkl0MumYhjeNIByI1oJ4zeD2S6zZOQAdNdxKdxvXnhd8AYeOt6yfAAKXzbiAHTy7nP@2/eZl5PvtqlG1YXvnInjyNlJF/BJJX26VE8jlws9uOVF0@XN8H6x/@@Nl9azIYCHddf85XXP7/zaicl4AsHRd//t7k6BHQHTlLGm4GrTIJm0MagenjvZIl3HGFbIlJaFY223/w0)

Ungolfed:

```c
// Day of week: Su=0, M=1, Tu=2, W=3, Th=4, F=5, Sa=6
#define z(d)(*d-'S'?*d-'T'?*d-'M'?*d-'W'?5:3:1:d[1]-'u'?4:2:d[1]-'u'?6:0)
// Add one week if the target day of week precedes the current one
#define Z(d,e)(d-e+(d-e<0?7:0))
t[20], // struct tm for time conversions (important parts are initialized each run through)
a, b, // week numbers
x, // temporary for month calculation
n, y; // month and year
char *m, *d, *e; // original string versions of days, month and year
f(int*s) {
  sscanf(s,"%d %ms %ms %d %ms %d",&y,&m,&d,&a,&e,&b); // get the parsed data
  t[5]=y-=1900; // adjust the year
  x=*m-78; // get most values into single-digit
  // Month: Ja=0 F=1 M_r=2 Ap=3 M_y=4 J_n=5 J_l=6 Au=7 S=8 O=9 N=10 (else) 11
  //t[4]=n=*m-'J'?*m-'M'?*m-'A'?*m-'F'?*m-'S'?*m-'O'?*m-'N'?11:10:9:8:1:m[1]-'p'?7:3:m[2]-'r'?2:4:m[1]-'a'?m[2]-'n'?6:5:0;
  t[4]=n=x+4?~x?x+13?x+8?x-5?x-1?x?11:10:9:8:1:m[1]-112?7:3:m[2]-114?2:4:m[1]-97?m[2]-110?6:5:0;
  t[3]=1; // start on the first day of the month
  mktime(&t); // get the day of week information
  t[3]+=Z(z(e),t[6])+(a+b-2)*7+Z(z(d),z(e)); // add offsets
  mktime(&t); // convert to canonical form
  t[4]-n|t[5]-y?printf("%04d-%02d-%02d",y+1900,n+1,t[3]); // only print date if it is still inside the month
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 204  (or 126?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

With strict I/O and outputting `NA` when the date goes beyond the given input month+year: **204 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:

```
"Y`т‰0Kθ4ÖUD<i\28X+ë<7%É31α}‹iY¬>0ëY1¾ǝDÅsD12‹i>1ë\1Dǝ¤>2}}ǝV"ˆ$”‚æ‡‰…ä†ï€¿…Ë…ê†Ä…æ…Ì…Í……”#s#©1èk>Dˆ®н)V®2ô¦RvyθFNĀi¯н.V}[Y`UD3‹©12*+>₂*T÷®Xα©т%D4÷®т÷©4÷®·(O7%”ŒÍ‹Ó‹ŽŒ¹ŒêŒÛŠ¯”#yнkQ#¯н.V]YÂT‰J'-ýsÅs¯θÊi„NA
```

The cumbersome I/O and 05AB1E's lack of date builtins make for a pretty big program.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JZBdSwJBFIb/yqJJpRTOKtiFLARLF0VGoeKSgUp7sUgJLQleLAxLBX3dGHRRbBjIkh@4CYF6sQVzWrwQFv0L80e2GYM5D@95YeY9c2p6uaKpQRBSSguT4s/4nj9OwnNOTmtFcasQg146FYHbBPKHBsUTTSF9KQ49BZHvqSXDtS4jkfsSgl4RyVOLtCXRMKZWPjS7WaHYovgFbIrf2dsU29CmuAUONfvkh7f3HF3uXXFlczxwPDIsjxXWw6SD4KMqybMbMpi763kyEOGL2Ef1hj/eyfxijThzdzNvHCulnJxg47ALYjQmUdOMZmFEBgV/SDoLMyInebcwGTtLSUZrB6kIS/GaPHICTwye6zXJhDldVq9eizh8jMbcrR6G/5NOFDCz7Ee7qxvg6mwLxPHHcKdR/JbZDgIxLiIhU6urZxX1QsheqvppuSEgYb92vhR/) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##hZHva9NAGMff56842hV10625dkwhZAxiXyh2qF1dsYJpc9CwmYxknfRFIAQt@OtNBV8okQmj2HW0DgZrX0ThztIXg9D@C/eP1Lt0s2NvBnffPPe9T57nubuSalcmZXUXyKBsamjRtNWSjoAkgfvrGWE1Bmi9AWKrk1ih@HLsUfdX8mHYS5MvG4qkF@HdzQXSllYS5F1KDI8d6vb1Aj6Sk6RdEPHvoa@Qt7YiQu7LImkXRWXo4wMZOs7Qz8fO6nPU9an7lTSp@4Plpm6THFB3n3Spd4T/8OUHLofce8OjJpePXD4xiYYft@O4JZKfW7JyVsedUXArjzuQnODmk71a2Mtk/7o67o6CxbzznJ1iQ0mxftgfcH5Bpp43nyOnuLMZHuPW2Esoab4ae0xbUYhPb66vJFiZQYPX7JPPTAbBoIH7zDlk89tgH3d5H7VRsPU4Pi31okC8HDvSgxt3SGCza8DdsEfe69T9nl2bOLfxicAvWHhd0bcRsJCqAd0QNFMAYMnc2V2avsP558rTSGAuYg00gUkogqy5h16VkAVyVWRrag2I4JFpRIHAgOT1gILKUyBj6dyG4BnSjHOWIeI9sLZj6duX7Qs2SpECGVSyqqpV@18jfSXHZWa2swxylao1g@Csl6dVY0pcBMvCPw).

With flexible I/O and just continue calculating instead of outputting `NA`: **126 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:

```
"Y`т‰0Kθ4ÖUD<i\28X+ë<7%É31α}‹iY¬>0ëY1¾ǝDÅsD12‹i>1ë\1Dǝ¤>2}}ǝV"ˆ1šVvyθFNĀi¯н.V}[Y`UD3‹©12*+>₂*T÷®Xα©т%D4÷®т÷©4÷®·(O7%yнQ#¯н.V]Y
```

Two inputs in the formats `[month,year]` and `[[weekday2,amount2],[weekday1,amount1]]`, where `month` is an integer `1-12` and `weekday` are integers `0-6` for Saturday to Friday.
Outputs in the format `[day,month,year]`.

Still pretty big with the manual calculations, but apparently more than 1/3rd of my top program's bytes are to deal with just the I/O formats.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKTLhYtOjhg0G3ud2mByeFupikxljZBGhfXi1jbnq4U5jw3Mbax817MyMPLTGzuDw6kjDQ/uOz3U53FrsYmgEErczPLw6xtDl@NxDS@yMamuPzw1TOt1meHRhWFnluR1ufkcaMg@tv7BXL6w2OjIh1MUYqOXQSkMjLW27R01NWiGHtx9aF3Fu46GVF5tUXUxAvItNQHIlmHlou4a/uWrlhb2ByhAzYiP//482NNQxMjAyjOWKjjbWMYzViTYBkrEA)

**Explanation (of the larger strict I/O version):**

Step 0: Create a function to go to the next day, which we'll re-use later on (see [this 05AB1E answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173126/52210) for an in-depth explanation of how we're going to the next day manually of a given date):

```python
"Y`т‰0Kθ4ÖUD<i\28X+ë<7%É31α}‹iY¬>0ëY1¾ǝDÅsD12‹i>1ë\1Dǝ¤>2}}ǝV"
                 # Push this string to act as function later on with an eval
 ˆ               # Add it to the global array†
```

<sup>† The reason I use the global array instead of a variable: I'm already using all three `U/X`, `V/Y`, and `©®` variable setters/getters in the actual manual date calculations.</sup>

Step 1: Extract the year and month from the input, and parse it as `[1,m,y]` triplet-list:

```python
$                # Push 1 and the input-string
 ”‚æ‡‰…ä†ï€¿…Ë…ê†Ä…æ…Ì…Í……”
                 # Push dictionary string "January February March April May June July August September October November December"
  #              # Split it on spaces to a list
   s             # Swap so the input-string is at the top of the stack
    #            # Split it on spaces as well
     ©           # Store this sextuple input-list in variable `®` (without popping)
      1è         # Pop and get the Month at (0-based) index 1
        k        # Get the (0-based) index of this month in the list
         >       # Increase it by 1 to a 1-based index
          Dˆ     # Add a copy to the global array as well
            ®    # Push the input-list of variable `®` again
             н   # Pop and leave its first item (the year)
              )  # Wrap all three values into a list: [1,m,y]
               V # Pop and store it in variable `Y`
```

Step 2: Parse the remainder of the input-string, and start looping:

```python
®                # Push the input-list from variable `®` again
 2ô              # Split it into parts of size 2
   ¦             # Remove the first part (the [year,"Month"])
    R            # Reverse the other two parts
     v           # For each over the pairs `y` in the pair:
      yθ         #  Push the last item of the current pair (the amount of days)
        F        #  Pop and inner loop that many times:
         NĀi     #   If it's NOT the first iteration:
            ¯н.V #    Go to the next day
                 #    by evaluating the first item of the global array of step 0
           }     #   Close the if-statement
         [       #   Start an inner infinite loop:
```

Step 3a: Calculate the DayOfWeek of the current date as `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` for `[Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday]` respectively (see again [this 05AB1E answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173126/52210) for an in-depth explanation of how I calculate the Day of the Week manually of a given date):

```python
Y`UD3‹©12*+>₂*T÷®Xα©т%D4÷®т÷©4÷®·(O7%
```

Step 3b+c: If this day is equal to the input-date of the current pair `y`, stop the infinite loop. If not, go to the next day and continue looping.

```python
”ŒÍ‹Ó‹ŽŒ¹ŒêŒÛŠ¯” #    Push dictionary string "Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday"
 #               #    Split it on spaces to a list
  yн             #    Push the first item of the current pair (the day)
    k            #    Get its 0-based index in the list of weekdays
     Q           #    Check whether it's equal to the calculated DayOfWeek from step 3a
      #          #    If they're equal:
      #          #     Stop the inner infinite loop
       ¯н.V      #    (Else) Go to the next day by evaluating step 0 again
```

Step 4: Format the resulting date to the desired output-format:

```python
]                # Close the three loops
 Y               # Push the resulting date `Y`
  Â              # Bifurcate this triplet; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
   T‰J           # Format the day/month with leading 0:
   T‰            #  Divmod each inner value by 10
     J           #  Join each inner pair together
      '-ý       '# Join the triplet-list with "-" delimiter
  s              # Swap the triplet to the top of the stack again
   Ås            # Only leave its middle item (the month)
     ¯θ          # Push the last item of the global array (the parsed input-month)
       Êi        # If they are NOT equal:
         „NA     #  Push string "NA"
                 # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”‚æ‡‰…ä†ï€¿…Ë…ê†Ä…æ…Ì…Í……”` is `"January February March April May June July August September October November December"` and `”ŒÍ‹Ó‹ŽŒ¹ŒêŒÛŠ¯”` is `"Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday"`.

Both `"ˆ$”‚æ‡‰…ä†ï€¿…Ë…ê†Ä…æ…Ì…Í……”#I#1èk>` and `”ŒÍ‹Ó‹ŽŒ¹ŒêŒÛŠ¯”#yнk` can probably be golfed a bit with magic numbers of some sort, but since I suck at those and I also couldn't really be bothered in an answer already this big because of manual date calculations, the indexing into dictionary strings will do for now.

Comment: OP has confirmed that any undefined behaviour, except an error, is acceptable for the "NA" test cases.

Comment: @Shaggy His comment to me contradicts that lol.. "it should not return a date and should not result in an error". But I'll just look at his reply to you. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen these comments do not contradict. consider them together.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 262 bytes

```go
import."time"
func f(y,m,d,e string,n,o int)string{t,_:=Parse("2006January",y+m)
D,i,j:=Hour*24,1,1
for t.Weekday().String()!=e{t=t.Add(D)}
for;j<o;j++{t=t.Add(D*7)}
for t.Weekday().String()!=d{t=t.Add(D)}
for;i<n;i++{t=t.Add(D*7)}
return t.Format("2006-01-02")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVPRatswFGV7GNRfofnJbmRjKUnX2vWDIQtjsFBIoYwstGqspEptychyWQj5kr2UwR72SdvXTIqcZG0Ze7rXR-ceXd17_O37Qjz-SioyuycLCkrCuMPKSkgVuvNSufuPWknGF_UTYCb4g_ujUfPg9PerN7sDxUrqOvOGz8DcW8ES5pACWw45FIBx5dvPtYLXcXpBZE09F0fRyUfCGyJXLlx1St8ZQAaXcfpBNPIY9yCCyJkLCVR4Rel9TlaeH463Op7_NqVrlaowy3Nv4G8ML1mei2TZ6Rzw43f25B8K-QsFds4T9kJBUtVIrkWGQpZE2c6DCAURdv1NO47XP9WqoiAzD29mCqw_UyIh-CS4uoNgQFaoHUkCRk2JzFASA-M9bHBs8fdfK6o17MnGsbM1q_J8sHZEnN7gCCMwEg-0vKUSXDa01q8DyNxnE0MIkOnR0Wn0P2605XYtd0BnljuUzDAwuKI535VZNtYFmo3OQFZJVjxhtGWGis6CqBegyAh3wZDeSrPvfRO958pd3XCAT5_RD6Q-uLxrZMsfZYaHD_2OG25Ju6SvOTdOHaeTaba2XriGBYhTIAnX9h9XBVOegMD9wl0z2yMap0NGi7z2Ct854sgYNlOCeXTSnRoE_4X0DVKnpKooz70agmy79phOomm7e52jqTWATrFNsU57OjVOiPUd29XHWrrdvD4-mW58Z9cxiVPbb712LrQnVME9AvXfRkJrMxK2RiOhuamN2ERzRxuxbyRbxz4-2vgH)

Extremely similar to my solution for ["Get the date of the nth day of week in a given year and month"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257397/77309).

For the `NA` test cases, it continues on to the next month/year until it finds the `n`-th `d`day after the `o`-th `e`day.

#### Explanation

```go
import."time"
func f(y,m,d,e string,n,o int)string{
t,_:=Parse("2006January",y+m)
D:=Hour*24
```

Some initial setup: getting the 1st of month `m` in the year `y`, and defining a `D`ay variable.

```go
for t.Weekday().String()!=e{t=t.Add(D)}
for j:=1;j<o;j++{t=t.Add(D*7)}
```

Skip forward to the `o`-th `e`day.

```go
for t.Weekday().String()!=d{t=t.Add(D)}
for i:=1;i<n;i++{t=t.Add(D*7)}
```

Skip forward to the `n`-th `d`day.

```go
return t.Format("2006-01-02")}
```

Return a formatted date.